# Can't convert this into VB.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, c#-to-vb.net

I'm trying to convert the following into vb.net. Thanks in advance

```
   Categories.DataSource = objDT.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
        .Select(r => new { Attendee = r.Field<string>("Attendee"), Item = r.Field<string>("Item") })
        .GroupBy(v => v.Attendee)
        .Select(g => new { Attendee = g.Key, Item = g.ToList() });
```

This is where I get stuck, I have tried two different methods but still nothing works:

```
Categories.DataSource = objDT.AsEnumerable() _
    .Select(Function(r) New With {.Attendee = r.Field(Of String)("Attendee"), .Item = r.Field(Of String)("Item")}) _
    .GroupBy(Function(v) v.Field(Of String)("Attendee")) _
    .Select(Function(g) Attendee = g.Key)
```

or

```
Categories.DataSource = objDT.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow)().AsEnumerable _
    .Select New Object(){ Function(r As DataRow) Attendee = r.Field(Of String)("Attendee"), Item = r.Field(Of String)("Item")} _
.GroupBy( Function(v) v.Category) _
.Select( Function(g) new { Category = g.Key, Numbers = g.ToList() }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
  Categories.DataSource = objDT.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow)().Select(Function(r) New With { _
 .Attendee = r.Field(Of String)("Attendee"), _
 .Item = r.Field(Of String)("Item") _
}).GroupBy(Function(v) v.Attendee).Select(Function(g) New With { _
 .Attendee = g.Key, _
 .Item = g.ToList() _
})
```

Object Class  (New Object() With {})is different than anonymous type (New With {}).

You can use this site in the future : http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/ . It works pretty well for most of the conversions.

Comment: Thank you Matthieu, this method worked! I'll remember to try your conversion link above.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
Categories.DataSource = objDT.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow)() _
    .Select(Function(r) New With {.Attendee = r.Field(Of String)("Attendee"), .Item = r.Field(Of String)("Item")}) _
    .GroupBy(Function(v) v.Attendee) _
    .Select(Function(g) New With { .Attendee = g.Key, .Item = g.ToList()})
```

Comment: Thank you JaredPar your solution also worked just as well! Which I could also give you green check mark. Thanks :)